# run multiple mysql queries as 1 query

Tags: mysql

im trying to take 3 sql queries and insert them into 1 table without getting the null value's and using a group by number as to not get duplicate numbers in the same column.

I have the issue where running query 1 leaves me with a bunch of null data values
and running query 2 doesnt group the numbers resulting in thousands of rows numbers only go up to 100

QUERY 1

```
insert into table ( number)
select number as 1day from table where date = CURDATE() - interval 1day group by number
 insert into table ( number)
select number as 2day from table where date = CURDATE() - interval 1day group by number
insert into table ( number)
select number as 7day from table where date = CURDATE() - interval 1day group by number
```

so i try to run

QUERY 2

```
insert into table (number,number,number)
select 
*
 from
(select number as 1day from test.test where date = curdate() - interval 1 day group by 
 number) as 1day,
(select number as 2day from test.test where date > curdate() - interval 2 day group by 
 number) as 2day,
 (select number as 7day from test.test where date > curdate() - interval 7 day group 
 by number) as 7day;
```

[image: 1st query][image: 2nd query]

Comment: You question is not so clear. Adding some sample data and expected result will be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the question and attached some images of the data so hopefully it is a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

try the below:

```
insert into table (number,number,number)
select 
table.1day,table.2day,table.7day
 from
((select number from test.test where date = curdate() - interval 1 day group by 
 number) as 1day,
(select numberfrom test.test where date > curdate() - interval 2 day group by 
 number) as 2day,
 (select number from test.test where date > curdate() - interval 7 day group 
 by number) as 7day) as table
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work 

table.1day,table.2day,table.7day ( it doesnt like this bit of the query)

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case one.number when two.number then null else one.number end) as '1day',(case two.number <= third.number when true then (case one.number = two.number when true then null else two.number end)  else (case one.number = two.number when false then null else two.number end) end) as '2day',(case (third.number < one.number and third.number = two.number) when true then null else third.number end) as '7day'
from (
(select x.number
from (
(select number,'1day' as 'type' from testtable where date = curdate() - interval 1 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'2day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 2 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'7day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 7 day group by number)) as x
where x.type='2day' order by x.number) as two,
(select x.number
from (
(select number,'1day' as 'type' from testtable where date = curdate() - interval 1 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'2day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 2 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'7day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 7 day group by number)) as x
where x.type='1day' order by x.number) as one,
(select x.number
from (
(select number,'1day' as 'type' from testtable where date = curdate() - interval 1 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'2day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 2 day group by number)
union all
(select number,'7day' as 'type' from testtable where date > curdate() - interval 7 day group by number)) as x
where x.type='7day' order by x.number) as third
)
where ((one.number = two.number) or  (one.number is null or two.number is null)) or
((third.number = two.number) or  (two.number is null or third.number is null))
```

Comment: this is the closest answer to your concern

Comment: I had 2 problems when runnin this the 1st i end up with a lot of null value's the second it is not running the group by funtion? i am happy to run three different insert into statement to get the group by function working properly but how would i delete null value's from the table without deleting the whole row that the null value is on

Comment: you actually can't unless you take 1day or 2day or 7day each seperately and remove the null entries

Comment: as in have them in 3 separate tables?

Comment: exactly as there is no other way

Comment: okay if i add them into three different table am i able to then extract the data into 1 table on a php page?

Comment: okay sorry i have 1 more question they go into the table perfectly and when i run individual queries e.g. select data from table it returns fine but if i run the following

    select*from 
    (SELECT 1day from test.bc1)as 1day,
    (SELECT 2day as 2day from test.bc2) as 2day,
    (SELECT 7day as 7day from test.bc7)as 7day;

it adds a lot of duplicate entries even though there are no duplicate entries in any of the tables.